# GAE Java Standard Env Deployment Issue - Process exited with error code 1

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have Eclipse GAE Java project setup, that had no issues until recently. Eclipse version is "Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. - Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)". Google cloud platform plugin installed - Google Cloud Platform for Eclipse    1.8.2.201906242031. I am used to just right click - Deploy to Standard Environment. Suddenly, this stopped working and I am getting the message as 
"Process exited with error code 1". In the console, only message I see is "The system cannot find the path specified." I am getting same message from gcloud command line. I am stuck at this point and am unable to deploy. I checked the Build path and it is pointing to JDK and not JRE.

Did anyone have the same issue. Does anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this. Please advise.

Comment: To confirm, you tried deploying with gcloud command directly on the CLI console, and you got the error "The system cannot find the path specified.", correct?. Also, have you recently located files under "WEB-INF" folder instead of "src/main/resources" ? [1] 
__
[1] https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-maven-plugin/issues/229#issuecomment-341773599

Comment: Yes, I tried both from eclipse and gcloud CLI and get the same error without any other details. Not sure what you mean by located files under WEB-INF, the project structure did not change at all. Also, I am not using maven like in the link, used to deploying using right click from Eclipse. Also tried gcloud CLI

Comment: Understood, in that case could you try reinstalling the latest version of the Google Cloud SDK?  to rule out the possibility of the SKD installation being corrupted/misconfigured. If that doesn't work, could you run the gcloud command using the flags: "--verbosity  --log-http " and sharing the results in the question? | to uninstall (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/uninstall-cloud-sdk), to install (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/install)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I got it resolved. The issue was with pyton path on my machine. After spending multiple hours to figure out what the issue was, all I had to do was update the variable CLOUDSDK_PYTHON to the right version of python 2.7 version exe file. For some reason the system variable got deleted.

Comment: Excellent, glad to know that you were able to solved it!.